# How to connect to database from oracle forms programmatically

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am using oracle forms 6i,
I want to connect to database programmatically using pl/sql code

I don't want final user to insert username and password and database name when forms run like this image:

.[image: I don't want final user to face this dialog]

I used pre-form trigger like this:

```
begin
    execute 'connect to hr/hr@yemensoft';   
end;
```

But it returns with errors;

> `error 103 at line2, column 10 encountered the symbol "connect to hr/hr@yemensoft" when expecting one of the following: :=.(@%;`

Comment: And the returned error is..?

Comment: error 103 at line2, column 10
encountered the symbol "connect to hr/hr@yemensoft" when expecting one of the following: :=.(@%; ....

Comment: Explanation: `execute` is for running `PL/SQL`. `connect` is SQL*Plus syntax, not PL/SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use the `LOGON` built-in procedure:

```
LOGON('hr', 'hr@yemensoft');
```

> LOGON Built-in
>
> Description: Performs the default Oracle Forms logon processing with an indicated username and password. Call this procedure from an On-Logon trigger when you want to augment default logon processing. 
>   Syntax
>
> ```
> PROCEDURE LOGON(username VARCHAR2, password VARCHAR2); 
> PROCEDURE LOGON(username VARCHAR2, password VARCHAR2, logon_screen_on_error BOOLEAN);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is in your `ON-LOGON` trigger to have:

```
LOGON('hr', 'hr'||'@'||Get_Application_Property(CONNECT_STRING), false);
```

Make sure to add something like this in your `formsweb.cfg`:

```
[your-conf-for-db-yemensoft]
...
...
userid=@yemensoft
```